# how to check if admin exist in json

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I am building an app with vuejs. I am getting a json data from an api.

The json contains two users.

One of the user has admin role and the other  does not have admin role

I want to check if the user has admin role when it displays the users

json data

users array object

```
{
    "users": [{
        "id": "1f7524c5-108e-4f33-a58e-1b8efbbac7c",
        "name": "nwafor nnamdi",
        "email": "nna@gmail.com",
        "phone": "+2348032547845",
        "admin": {
            "id": "1f0e88a1-ac3d-480f-b8ca-e3c2481039c7",
            "user_id": "1f7524c5-108e-4f33-a58e-1b8efbbac7c",
            "role": "manager",
            "created_at": "2021-12-31T10:35:10.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-12-31T11:08:51.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    }, {
        "id": "jduw-dieke-9e8ej-eje8-ej383j",
        "name": "admin",
        "email": "admin@gmail.com",
        "phone": "08032547856"
    }]
   }


<tr v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
  <td>
  <button id="make-admin" @click="changeRole('none')" v-if="user.admin && user.admin.role == 'manager'"> Remove Manager</button>
  <button id="make-admin" @click="changeRole('manager')"  v-else-if="user.admin && user.admin.role == 'super'"> Remove Super Admin</button>
  <button id="make-admin"  @click="changeRole('super')" v-if="user.admin && user.admin.role == 'none'"> Super Admin</button>
  <button id="make-admin"  @click="changeRole('super')" v-if="user.admin && user.admin.role == 'none'"> Manager</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am getting user.admin is null

Comment: can you try to print value of `user` object?

Comment: I have updated my question. Users is an array of user objects @ParthPatel

Comment: You will get exactly what you have. If user.admin === null this means it's really null, and your assumptions on data are wrong. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: Is your json data in proper format?

Comment: Your users array is not that you think. First, that json in your question, is bad formed, so probably you write for your own. As @ParthPatel said, print user object.

Comment: @Kalamarico  I have updated my question with the correct array object

Comment: I think, in that "v-for" you are not iterating over your "data" array inside that json. In your definition of "users", try to add a console.log trace and display this variable

Comment: @Kalamarico I have changed it to users but I am getting the same error

Comment: You should provide a way to reproduce, as @EstusFlask said.

Comment: @etranz I think you are confused with the "data" object of vue components, if you provide, uploading your code, a link where we saw and reproduce the problem, we could help you

Comment: @etranz or try to share all the code of your Vue component in your question (if it's possible of course). I'm thinking that your problem solves very easy

Answer (score 1):

Something like following ?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
       users: [{
        "id": "1f7524c5-108e-4f33-a58e-1b8efbbac7c",
        "name": "nwafor nnamdi",
        "email": "nna@gmail.com",
        "phone": "+2348032547845",
        "admin": {
            "id": "1f0e88a1-ac3d-480f-b8ca-e3c2481039c7",
            "user_id": "1f7524c5-108e-4f33-a58e-1b8efbbac7c",
            "role": "manager",
            "created_at": "2021-12-31T10:35:10.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-12-31T11:08:51.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null
          }
        }, 
        {
            "id": "jduw-dieke-9e8ej-eje8-ej383j",
            "name": "admin",
            "email": "admin@gmail.com",
            "phone": "08032547856",
        }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<table>
<tr v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
  <td>
    <button id="make-admin" @click="changeRole('none')" v-if="user.admin?.role == 'manager'"> Remove Manager</button>
    <button id="make-admin" @click="changeRole('manager')"  v-else-if="user.admin?.role == 'super'"> Remove Super Admin</button>
    <button id="make-admin"  @click="changeRole('super')" v-if="user.admin?.role == 'none'"> Super Admin</button>
    <button id="make-admin"  @click="changeRole('super')" v-if="user.admin?.role == 'none'"> Manager</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```